# Are there airborne poop particles flying around bathrooms?

Tags: hygiene, toilets

I've heard claims of airborne poop particles that fly into the air everytime one flushes a toilet. Here's some examples:

- [HERE](http://www.tbyil.com/Exposed_Toothbrushes.htm) someone states that flushing the toilet "aerosolizes" water/poop into the air
- [HERE](http://offbeathome.com/2011/04/make-your-bathroom-smell-less-like-poop) is another article referencing such high flying particles
- [HERE](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/features/germs-in-bathroom) is a WebMD article featuring the same

The central quote from the last two is from Charles Gerba, PhD, a professor of microbiology at University of Arizona in Tucson:

> Polluted water vapor erupts out of the flushing toilet bowl and it can take several hours for these particles to finally settle — not to mention where.

Similarly, I've heard that hand dryers spew these particles out onto one's hands.

- [HERE](http://agoraphilia.blogspot.com/2007/09/why-i-hate-restroom-hand-dryers.html) is an example of a claim like that
- [HERE](http://community.discovery.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/7501919888/m/80419542301) is a short forum discussion about the same

True? Worrisome? Also, I'd love any references as to the method of making the particles airborne if they do occur. I had the understanding that to aerosolize, one needed to overcome the cohesive forces of the material -- hence forcing them apart into small particles via strong jets of air vs. the nominal droplet size of the liquid.

I'm skeptical that a toilets have the power necessary to aerosolize, except for perhaps the "jet-powered" public toilets.

Comment: Be aware that there are many different toilet designs, and the popular designs in North America (e.g. siphoning) are not used everywhere (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flush_toilet). Non-siphoning designs appear to have more forceful water-splashing.

Comment: See also http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/is-it-more-hygenic-to-keep-the-lid-down-on-the-toilet-after-use

Comment: If you can smell it, then this means that chemicals from the poop are reaching your nose. They have to get there somehow...

Comment: @lagerbaer scientifically one must presuppose that if it can be smelt, it has indeed been dealt.

Comment: "There's poo everywhere. What are we gonna do!?" - Bacteria are normal. Get over it. :-)

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Your reasoning is second to none. If I had the connections I'd nominate you for an Ig Nobel in talking sh|t.

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Chemicals from it are reaching your nose, but that doesn't imply anything about bacteria or particulate matter. It's a bit like equating smelling food and eating it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Mythbuster Episode 11 of 2004 Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_%282004_season%29#Toothbrush_Surprise) showed that fecal matter did seem to get everywhere, and the explanation appeared to be through aerosol, or at least flung out of the toilet somehow.

Comment: The link to the video is gone, but I assume it is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2004_season)#Toothbrush_Surprise

Comment: Mythbusters a credible source, that is new :)

Comment: @Andra Their experiments were a bit rough-and-ready, but they were generally scientific and they showed their working. If their experiment found fecal matter being distributed around the bathroom, then yes, thats pretty credible. Of course I'd prefer a peer-reviewed publication.

Answer (score -1):

This subject received a lot of attention during the COVID-19 pandemic of 2020. For example, a NY Times [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/16/health/coronavirus-toilets-flushing.html) discusses the so-called "toilet plume":

> Scientists have found that in addition to clearing out whatever business you’ve left behind, flushing a toilet can generate a cloud of aerosol droplets that rises nearly three feet. Those droplets may linger in the air long enough to be inhaled by a shared toilet’s next user, or land on surfaces in the bathroom.
>
> This toilet plume isn’t just gross. In simulations, it can carry infectious coronavirus particles that are already present in the surrounding air or recently shed in a person’s stool. The research, published Tuesday in the journal [Physics of Fluids](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/5.0013318), adds to growing evidence that the coronavirus can be passed not only through respiratory droplets, but through virus-laden feces, too.

It also discusses the mechanism by which the aerosolized fecal matter occurs:

> A computer simulation of the toilet flushing mechanism showed that when water pours into the toilet and generates a vortex, it displaces air in the bowl. These vortices move upward and the centrifugal force pushes out about 6,000 tiny droplets and even tinier aerosol particles.
>
> Depending on the number of inlets in the toilet, flushing can force anywhere from 40 to 60 percent of the produced aerosols high above the seat.

Comment: I suppose there's rarely any point in discussing the Stack Exchange scores. But can anyone explain why the one answer got a score of 13 with very little explanation and comments that the one cited source is unreliable and the link goes nowhere; while this second answer quotes scientific analysis from the New York Times, with good links, and earned a score of 0?

Comment: @Chaim: One has been gathering votes for 9 years (during much of which the link probably worked). The other is two days old.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yeah, when I posted the comment yesterday I had not noticed the timing. I agree that timing explains a lot. I think, though, that this is an important, inherent problem in the Stack Exchange method of scoring questions and answers, almost necessarily creating and a disconnect between scores and actual merit.